# Need help on understanding how system call (int 0x80,etc) are handled

Tags: assembly, kernel

I'm currently writing a kernel, and I need help on understanding how system call are handled, because I can't find any documents that explained how they are defined and handled.

Comment: Did you read _CHAPTER 6 INTERRUPT AND EXCEPTION HANDLING_ in the _Intel® 64 and IA-32 Architectures Software Developer's Manual Volume 3: System Programming Guide_? Did you read the pages about `syscall`/`sysenter` in the instruction set reference? Did you read the [System calls page on osdev](https://wiki.osdev.org/System_Calls)? Have you looked at open source OS code? What exactly do you have a problem with? Be specific.

Comment: What I need is how to DEFINE a interrupt(like int 0x80)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [How syscall knows where to jump?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56854297/how-syscall-knows-where-to-jump)

Comment: @ClementPoon Put an appropriate entry into the [IDT](https://wiki.osdev.org/Interrupt_Descriptor_Table).

Comment: My answer on [What happens if you use the 32-bit int 0x80 Linux ABI in 64-bit code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46087730) shows some of the kernel side of dispatching system calls via the table of function pointers, indexed by the call number in RAX.  For the x86 IDT part, [What does "int 0x80" mean in assembly code?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/1817577)

Comment: My kernel uses the real mode instead of protected mode.

Comment: Then it's much simpler: simply put the address of the interrupt handler into an appropriate spot in the IVT.

Comment: I'm literally asking for how to PUT the address of the interrupt handler code into IVT.